# mixed up data in firebase database data

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am new to firebase and Android programming in general. In my app I'm simply saving fullName, password, phoneNumber, Email, gender and a confirmed password. All these fields get stored in the database but their mixed up

Users
+23407066082195
email: '0000'

fullName: '+23407066082195'

gender: 'male'

password: 'k..gmail.com'

phoneNo: 'Tim...'

retypedPassword: '0000'

this is my code : for the first activity

```
 btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
 btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!validateEdtName() | !validateEdtEmail() | !validatePhoneNumber() | !validateEdtPassword() | !validateEdtRePassword() | !validateGender()) {
                return;
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selectedGender = findViewById(gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            String gender = selectedGender.getText().toString();

            String myName = fullName.getEditableText().toString().trim();
            String myEmail = email.getEditableText().toString().trim();
            String myPassword = password.getEditableText().toString().trim();
            String myRetypedPassword = retypedPassword.getEditableText().toString().trim();

            String getUserEnteredPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.getEditableText().toString().trim();
            String phoneNo = "+" + countryCodePicker.getFullNumber() + getUserEnteredPhoneNumber;

            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, VerifyOTP.class);

            intent.putExtra("PhoneNumber", phoneNo);
            //intent.putExtra("fullName", fullName);
            intent.putExtra("myName", myName);
            intent.putExtra("myEmail", myEmail);
            intent.putExtra("myPassword", myPassword);
            intent.putExtra("myRetypedPassword", myRetypedPassword);
            intent.putExtra("gender", gender);

            startActivity(intent);
```

for the next activity: created a class to hold the strings which is the `UserHelperClass`

```
FirebaseDatabase rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference reference = rootNode.getReference("Users");

UserHelperClass addNewUser = new UserHelperClass(fullName,phoneNo,password,email,retypedPassword,gender);
reference.child(phoneNo).setValue(addNewUser);
```

any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analyzed your code. Either you haven't correctly initialized your `EditText`s (maybe their ids aren't correct) or you haven't correctly implemented the constructor of `UserHelperClass`. Check both of them, you will probably see the bug.

P.S. I would encourage you to check [Parcelable documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html?hl=ID). It is for sharing objects via intents.

Comment: Thank u so much @Tuqay. It turns out it was the constructor and thanks for the tip